# higher SAS voluntary wait time reading observations

Tags: performance, time, sas, delay, wait

I have a unique requriment. I have 4 SAS datasets in sas library (p4,A,B,C). I have to read 1 observation from A,do some processing , store in temp dataset. Read 1 observation from B,do some process and store in temp dataset. Read 1 observation from C and do some processing and store in temp dataset. Then write all the temp dataset in JSON format. I am using multiple data steps and PROC JSON.  It is taking lot of 'wall clock ' unusually.  below is the sample code. Is there any way better to do this to avoid program load delay and voluntary wait.

Comment: Can you show the log when `OPTIONS STIMER;` is active

Comment: Thanks. I have added the sas log .

Comment: Your posted code seem to be garbled. You have the start of a macro %DO loop without any end. You have a macro DEFINITION in the middle of the %DO loop instead of a macro CALL.

Comment: Thanks, i have end for DO loop. i just edited. The SAS datasets and LOG naming conventions are just renamed  for the sake of organisation security policy. The code I shared is the crux i have .

Comment: Can your reproduce the problem using sample or *fake* data the exhibits the same egregious run time performance ?  Writing JSON for 1 billion observations is going to take a while regardless.  Am I seeing correctly that the macro `output_json` is recursing ?

Comment: Thanks, Richard. I did match-merge and add the sequence number to the as was datasets instead of doing it in the DATA step and IF condition. Then I am doing the JSON step. I did testing a pseudo-code which I think is efficient compared to previous. Will come back for any additional help. Thanks all for support